# How can I fix things to resume work from a much earlier version of Node.js?

Tags: node.js, migration

I've just upgraded (/usr/local/bin/)node to 5.6.0, as installed by the .pkg package from nodejs.org, and am trying to port an older project to work with current Node.

I expect multiple issues needing straightening out from my code, but for the moment the (possibly obsolete) invocation is erroring out on code that is not my own. My best guess is that I am getting an incompatible mixture of two Node installations; if so, what is the best way to uninstall both versions completely and then install 5.6.0?

The error message I see is:

```
Inner Sanctum ~/archive/pragmatometer $ /usr/local/bin/node bin/www
module.js:440
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                 ^

Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 47, got 44.
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:440:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object. (/Users/christos/archive/pragmatometer/node_modules/scrypt/index.js:3:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
```

What can / should I do to resolve this and go on to the next step of porting my code?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Based on other issues i've read it seems to be a problem with VERSION_STRING constants inside scripts in the node_modules folder. Try to delete the whole node_modules folder and run an `npm install` with the new node version currently installed to get fresh module installations.

Also i would suggest to checkout [n](https://github.com/tj/n), a very tiny node version manager that helps you switch between the different versions of node.

Comment: Thank you; I just tried that and got identical output / behavior from ``/usr/local/bin/node bin/www``.